# Separating out HTML and CSS code into two different locations creating problem with the HTML rendering. How to fix this?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML code that works well with CSS in the same file, but when I separate the HTML and css with an external .css the page the website is not looking good and I don't understand why. (I'm new in this):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Add padding to containers */

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}


/* Full-width input fields */

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}


/* Overwrite default styles of hr */

hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/* Set a style for the submit/register button */

.registerbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Add a blue text color to links */

a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}


/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */

.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>PhoneShop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/registro.css">
  <!--Para enlazar con el css-->
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Registro de usuario</h1>
      <p>Rellena estos campos para poder crear tu cuenta:</p>
      <hr>

      <label><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección de correo electrónico" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="psw" required>
      <hr>
      <p>Creando una cuenta aceptas <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">REGISTRARSE</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

When I do  in html file, the website looks good. Without adding css looks good too but the problem is when I add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/registro.css">` the website is piled.

[image]

Comment: Is the path correct?

Comment: @CarlBinalla yes

Comment: So no errors in the dev console? Can you also add the project directory?

Comment: Check your browser dev console if there is a 404 error for the css

Comment: Additionally you can also have a look at the resulting html source code in the browser (via right click) and then click on the css link to check it's correctness. Since your link is relative, the "css" folder has to be a subfolder of the html file using it. Maybe you mean "/css" with leading slash in case the css folder resides in the webapp's root.

Comment: Also please share with us exactly what is not appearing correctly. As it seems within [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26qf8y51/) your page looks to be appearing just fine. Does it appear like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/26qf8y51/1/) to you?

Comment: in browser-elements-styles the margin property is strikethrough

Comment: @Barrosy no, all elements are piled

Comment: can you try creating a fiddle for this?

Comment: Can you show your file structure?

Comment: Kinda looks to me that the file encodings are messed up. Check if both the CSS and HTML are `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how I solved this: just changing the name of the file the problem has been solved. Probably there was a conflict with the name of the other files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the CSS is only one section of your code that you are showing. I see there are things in your css that is not styled. for example there's no style for body or the paragraphs, header, h1. Just a example below to give you some idea. I hope it helps somehow.

```css
body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 60%;
}

p {
 line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #85929E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you saved the css file is the matter. or else you should mention the correct path in the  tag. For easy understands

Your Project Name

```
Html
Css(Folder need to create)
    registro.css
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the path in the `<link>` for you stylesheet, the path is from your `html` file to your `css` file.

The browser will always interpret / as the root of the hostname. For example, if my site was https://google.com/ and I specified /css/images.css then it would search for that at https://google.com/css/images.css.

If your project root was actually at /myproject/ it would not find the css file. Therefore, you need to determine where your project folder root is relative to the hostname, and specify that in your href notation

To check if your css is working, you can inspect the element (`CTRL + SHIFT + C` in google chrome) or just put try to display the css file in your brower with the absolute path like https://google.com/css/image.css